# How to find out if Email was successfully sent via PhoneGap SocialSharing plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, email, ionic2, socialshare

In my Ionic2 app I use the [SocialSharing Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) to share a document via Email. It works as expected, but I don't know from the success callback, if the Email was actually sent or if the user cancelled the action.

```
 SocialSharing.shareVieEmail(...).then((success) => {
        // here I want to know if Email has been sent successfully
        console.log(JSON.stringify(success)); // => "OK"
 }).catch(...)
```

Logging the success response just gives me a simple "OK", even if the Share Tool was closed.

How can I get an useful result to make sure the Email was sent?